# pthreads: do awaken threads have priority of reentering the critical section

Tags: pthreads, locking

I have read in the documentation of `pthread_cond_broadcast` the following:

> The thread(s) that are unblocked shall contend for the mutex according
>   to the scheduling policy (if applicable), and as if each had called
>   pthread_mutex_lock().

This raises a question: does a woken up thread has no precedence, when re-acquiring the mutex, over any other thread? In the example below, it would mean, that thread 2 may spin twice, calling `signal` two times, even if at the same time thread 1, even if woken up by the signal, did not even re-acquire the lock once, just waiting on `pthread_mutex_lock()`, somewhere within the call to `wait()`, like any other thread?

thread 1:

```
while(1) {
    lock
    wait
    unlock
}
```

thread 2:

```
while(1) {
    lock
    signal
    unlock
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the woken threads do not get any special priority when locking the mutex.  It is indeed possible for *thread 2* in your example to spin many times before *thread 1* is able to successfully acquire the lock and return from the `pthread_cond_wait()`.